# Strongloop Loopback - Localization of error messages

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

The loopback framework uses the strong-globalize module to provide translations for api responses. I've looked it up and see that there are a few default translations in the framework.

We want to use the 'Accept-Language' header field to determine which translation should be used. It is also mentioned in the strong-globalized readme.

But it is not working the translation is always english.

What we have to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a middleware and set the current language there.

```
//server/middlewares/lang.js
var negotiator = require('negotiator');
var SG = require('strong-globalize');

module.exports = function(options) {
  var allowedLangs = ['en', 'fa'];
  return function localeHandler(req, res, next) {
    var lang = new negotiator(req).language(allowedLangs);
    var g = SG();
    g.setLanguage(lang);    
    next();
  };
};
```

And

```
//server/middleware.json
 "inital:after": {
    "./middlewares/lang": {}
  },
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to translate the built-in validation error messages, you should translate in client or set the translated messages for the validation.

```
//custom-user.js

CustomUser.validations.email = lodash.reject(CustomUser.validations.email, function(val) {
    return val.validation === 'presence';
  });

CustomUser.validatesPresenceOf('email', {message: g.t('email-can-not-be-blank')});
```

Comment: For me it seems not to work. Messages are still in english: `The `CustomUser` instance is not valid. Details: `email` can't be blank (value: undefined); `username` User already exists (value: \"bob\").`. But it sets the correct language in strong-globalize. Maybe it is not a singleton and the settings get lost and a new instance with default settings is created?

Comment: @blacksheep_2011 It's singleton unless you create an instance by calling `var g = SG('some-name')` elsewhere

Comment: okay good to know. I will look into it with a debugger to see whats happening here

Comment: @blacksheep_2011 Do you want to translate validation error messages?? If you do, there is no way to translate them. You should translate them in client or set the correct message when calling validation methods

Comment: hmm thats bad and why are there translations in the framework for different languages? But okay then we need to do it in the different clients :/

Comment: @blacksheep_2011 I updated my answer. Is your language is defined in juggler?

Comment: I've tried it but it now only shows the translate key. It seems a little bit to hacky. We are now will write our own Angular 2 service which will translate the message and will share it between various clients. Thanks for your help!